# how to open my tabbarcontroller from scendelegate

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I have 2 viewcontrollers in a tabbar controller
i am trying to open the first viewcontroller, showing the whole tabbar from scene delegate

i have

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Main is the storyboard and ViewController is the file for the first ViewController

with this, I see the first view controller, but I can't see the tabbar options

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to instantiate the `UITabBarController` - not your first view controller.

In your `storyboard`, give your `UITabBarController` an identifier just like you did for your `ViewController`

After doing that, replace this line:

```
let viewController
    = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
```

with

```
let viewController
    = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourTabBarControllerIdentifier") as! UITabBarController
```

I believe this should work as you intended then

Comment: it says that Could not cast value

Comment: Made a small updated, you should cast it as a `UITabBarController` not a `ViewController` - try now